# mySQL: how to go along 3 different tables, referring to different column in each table but using primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to find out which schools had students that did not complete their exams in 2018. So I've got 3 tables set up being: `ExamInfo`, `ExamEntry` and `Students`. I'm going to try use the `ExamInfo` table to get information from the `Students` table though, I obviously only want the student information that did not complete their exam in 2018. Note: I'm looking for students that attended, though did not complete the exam, with this particular exam you can look at completed exam as passed exam.

Within `ExamInfo` I have the columns:

```
ExamInfo_Date --when exam took place, using to get year() condition
ExamInfo_ExamNo --unique student exam ID used to connect with other tables
ExamInfo_Completed --1 if completed, 0 if not.
...
```

Within `ExamEntry` I have the related columns:

```
ExamEntry_ExamNo --connected to ExamInfo table
ExamEntry_StudentId --unique studentId used to connect to Students table
ExamEntry_Date -- this is same as ExamInfo_Date if any relevance.
...
```

Within `Students` I have following columns:

```
Students_Id --this is related to ExamEntry_StudentId, PRIMARY KEY
Students_School --this is the school of which I wish to be my output.
...
```

I want my output to simply be a list of all schools that had students that did not complete their exams in 2018. Though my issue is with getting from the ExamInfo table, to finding the schools of which students did  not complete their exam.

So far I've:

```
SELECT a.Students_School, YEAR(l.ExamInfo_Date), l.ExamInfo_Completed
FROM ExamInfo l ??JOIN?? Students a
WHERE YEAR(l.ExamInfo_Date) = 2018
AND l.ExamInfo_Completed = 0
;
```

I'm not even sure if going through the `ExamEntry` table is necessary. I'm sure I'm meant to use a join, though unsure of how to appropriately use it.  Also, with my 3 different SELECT columns, I only wish for Students_School column to be output:

```
Students_School
---------------
Applederry
Barnet Boys
...
```

Comment: and the ON clause in that join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you need a `JOIN` -- two in fact.  Your table has *exams*, *students*, and a junction/association table that represents the many-to-many relationship between these entities.

So, I would expect the `FROM` clause to look like:

```
FROM ExamInfo e JOIN
     ExamEntry ee
     ON ee.ExamEntry_ExamNo = e.ExamNo JOIN
     Students s
     ON ee.ExamEntry_StudentId = s.Students_Id
```